# The proof for the Quadrature of a Trapeziod

Tags: proof-explanation, math-history, alternative-proof

I was wondering how does one go about proving this.

I have proven the quadrature of square and that of a triangle by forming a rectangle which leads to that of a square.

Is their any proofs already made available?

Any suggestions as how I can go about solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: If a "trapeziod" is a trapezium, you can find its area in the same way as any other quadrilateral, by drawing a diagonal, and so splitting it into two triangles.

Comment: Continuing from what your saying I would have to work from that of a triangle and lead backward like I have previously?